# Removing non square vector

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have

$A\overrightarrow{x} = B\overrightarrow{x}$ where $x$ is a vector in $R^2$

Can I claim

$A = B$, even though $x$ is not square and thus has no inverse?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? $2\times 2$ matrices?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your question is if there exists an $x$ such that $Ax=Bx$, can you conclude that $A=B$, answer would be no. For example, let $x=0$.

Suppose your quesiton is if $Ax=Bx$ for all $x$, then the answer is yes. $(A-B)x=0$ implies that $rank(A-B)=0$ and hence $A=B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
,
$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$,
and 
$
x=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$
Then, $Ax=Bx=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
$, 
but $A\not= B$.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Suppose $x=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\ 0\end{matrix}\right]$. Let $A=\left[\begin{matrix}a & c\\ b & d\end{matrix}\right]$ and $B=\left[\begin{matrix}a & e\\ b & f\end{matrix}\right]$, where $(c,d)\ne(e,f)$. Then $Ax=Bx=\left[\begin{matrix}a\\ b\end{matrix}\right]$, but $A\ne B$.